# How to change and return value from within a function

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am given a code block (C#) and want to change and return a new value (e.g., 9999) in the variable `gid`. However, the new value is not being returned. The original value used in the function call has not changed. How do I force a change in the value of the variable?

This is the code block:

```
public uint? GeneratePrimaryGid(DirectoryEntry de, uint? gid, int option)
{
    gid = 9999;
    return gid;
}
```

Unfortunately, passing it by reference, using the ref keyword, did not work.
As a comparison, here is the code segment for changing the Unix shell:

```
    public string GenerateShell(DirectoryEntry de, string shell, int option)
    {
        return shell;
    }
```

When I add this line before the return:
shell = "/bin/test";

I can see that the shell is set to /bin/test, even tho the value that was passed to the function was '/bin/bash'. In fact, when the parameter is of type 'string', the changes are reflected. Just not when the type is 'unit?'.

Comment: How are you observing that this method is *not* returning the value `9999`?  Or are you not using the return value and instead expecting `gid` to be a `ref` parameter?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: If you want to modify the parameter `gid`, you can accept it by reference (`ref uint gid`).

Comment: @David this code is part of a post-processor where the values can be changed and returned to an application. It is complied as a dll which is called by the application. The application takes Unix user account attributes  (e.g., primary group id - gid). When the application runs, I can see that the value of gid I provided, (e.g.,5555) is being used rather than the value in the post-processor (i.e., 9999).  Changing the value in the post-processors works when the parameter is of type 'string' but not 'uint ?'.

Comment: @Wohlstad can you provide an example of how I would do that in my code block?

Comment: @Lance: Instead of conceptually describing what the code is doing, can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Specifically indicate what observation(s) you are making in that example.  For example, what **specifically in the code shown** are you referring to when you say, *"I can see that the value of gid I provided, (e.g.,5555) is being used rather than the value in the post-processor (i.e., 9999)."*  Where in the code shown do you "see" this happening?

Comment: @Lance why do you need to return the same value you attempt to set in the `gid` parameter ? Isn't it enough to allow to pass `gid` and modify it (without returning it as well) ? Alternatively - just return the new value and assign it to a variable (without modifying the parameter). Why do you need both ?

Comment: @wohlstad I may want to return the same value because in some cases I do not want to change it. That is, for the Unix accounts, I may want to change some attributes (e.g., gid) and not for others. In that case I simply return the same value. There are different code segments for each Unix attribute, where the attribute value can be changed or returned as is. I want to show for example the code segment for the Unix shell attribute, but I don't know how to insert it here. I'll have to figure out how to insert it, so that you can see clearly what I mean.

Comment: @David I could take screenshots of the input data (i.e., the values that are passed to the functions) and the results (i.e, the values that are returned), but that may be a bit cumbersome to do.

Comment: @Lance: Pictures of data are unlikely to be useful. What *would* be useful is a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're struggling to conceptually describe. It *sounds like* you're confusing a method's returned value with the ability to update a reference. We would know for sure if you would provide an example of the problem. The code shown [demonstrably works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gXCztP) in terms of returning a value. Are you using that returned value? We don't know. Are you expecting something else to happen? We don't know. A [mcve] would help demonstrate.

Comment: @David I understand what you are asking, but I don't know if and how I could provide that information. The code I have is a small piece of a larger application. The engineers said we can change the value in the code segments, then return the new the value. I am pretty sure that we are not required to modify the calling parameter to use the keyword 'ref'. I'll need to think about how I can get the information you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

For this answer I'm simplifying the method signature to only contain the argument that's being changed:

```
public uint? GeneratePrimaryGid(uint? gid)
```

You stated:

> *I am given a code block and want to change and return a new value (e.g., 9999) in the variable `gid`*

Returning a value and changing a value are two different things. Your method is successfully *returning* the value you want here:

```
return gid;
```

The part that is possibly confusing you is that, because `uint?` is a [***value** type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types), you're only getting a *copy* of the value in the argument, so when you modify it, there is no change to the value of the variable on the caller's side. In order to change the value for the caller, you need to pass it *by reference*, using the `ref` keyword:

```
public uint? GeneratePrimaryGid(ref uint? gid)
{
    gid = 9999;
    return gid;
}
```

Now you are both returning the value *and* changing the value of the variable on the caller's side.